# Id increment by date and username

Tags: mysql, sql, database

This is what I have in my `order table`, how can I make the `order_ID` increment by using `user_Name and OrderDate`? Will it work?

```
 CREATE TABLE Order
 (
    order_ID int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    user_Name CHAR(15),
    product_ID CHAR(6) NOT NULL,
    order_Quantity int,
    OrderDate datetime NOT NULL DEFAULT GETDATE(),
    PRIMARY KEY(order_ID),
    FOREIGN KEY(user_Name) REFERENCES FUser(user_Name),
    FOREIGN KEY(product_ID) REFERENCES Product(product_ID)
);
```

Sample data:

```
order_ID    user_Name   product_ID  order_Quantity  OrderDate
1           blabla      a           2               11-11-08 13:23
1           blabla      b           1               11-11-08 13:23
1           blabla      c           1               11-11-08 13:23
2           c           a           2               11-11-08 13:23
2           c           b           2               11-11-08 13:23
```

Comment: What database are you using?  I see features of SQL Server, MySQL, and Oracle.  Please tag the question appropriately.  Also, sample data and desired results would help others understand your question.  And `Order` is not an acceptable table name in almost all databases.

Comment: MySQL workbench, i put Forder in for my table

Answer (score 0):

Order is a keyword (reserved words) for SQL
other keywords
http://std.csit.sci.tsu.ac.th/512021495/user1.1.php

Answer (score 0):

I never use Triggers myself (hard to debug)...but I am afraid that's what you need to get this custom job done...take a look at MSDN for (insert/update triggers)...it will surely help you...

Answer (score 0):

This is too long for a comment.

A table containing orders should have an `OrderId` column that is an auto-incremented primary key.  Your code is correct as written.

However, your table is *not* an orders table.  It is an order-product table.  So, I would write the data model like this:

```
CREATE TABLE Users (
    UserId NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY
    UserName VARCHAR(15)
);

CREATE TABLE Orders (
    OrderId int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
    UserId CHAR(15),
    OrderDate datetime NOT NULL DEFAULT GETDATE(),
    FOREIGN KEY (UserId) REFERENCES Users(UserId)
);

CREATE TABLE OrderProducts (
    OrderProductId int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
    ProductId int NOT NULL,
    OrderQuantity int,
    OrderDate datetime NOT NULL DEFAULT GETDATE(),
    FOREIGN KEY(ProductId) REFERENCES Product(ProductId)
);
```

Notes:

- All tables have an integer primary key.  This is best for foreign key references.
- There is no repeated data, such as `user_name`.  Things are stored in one place.
- This also uses my preferred naming conventions.